# Unit Testing using JUnit 5 and Mockito in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito, junit5

What are the things I need to test in Controller Testing, Service Testing and Repository Testing

Example:
In controller testing I should test:

1. If the endpoint will not work in different HTTP Methods
2. If the endpoint can receive request

I want to ask suggestions from other devs so I can learn the other goals in testing

I already know some of the parts that needs to be tested but I wanna ask if there are parts that I don't know

Comment: I would suggest checking for Unit Vs Integration testing and how can apply both of them. Also, consider to test the logic covering negative and positive tests

Comment: check or http status code, if response contains sth or not, null pointer exceptions etc.